# Not able to access object value by dynamic key in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections i.e parent and chilednodes.

parent collection :

```
{
    "_id" : "5e6c70e8996ddf1c28e14504",
    "startDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
    "active_id" : "child_vesrion_1",
    "child_id" : "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf30"
}
```

chilednodes:

```
{
    "_id" : "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf30",
    "startDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
    "endDate" : null,
    "child_vesrion_1" : {
        "childName" : "xyz",
        "createdDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
        "text" : "sometext",
        "type" : "notype"
    },
    "child_vesrion_2" : {
        "childName" : "abc",
        "createdDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
        "text" : "sometext2",
        "type" : "notype"
    },
    "active" : "child_vesrion_1"
}
```

I am trying to get parent detail along with active child version detail. Here i am using aggregation and lookup. 
I am constructing "finalList" field by using mongoDB $addFields. 
Here is my query;

```
 db.parent
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          '_id' : '5e6c70e8996ddf1c28e14504'
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'chilednodes',
          localField: 'child_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'child',
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          finalList: {
            $map: {
              input: '$child',
              as: 'c',
              in: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { "currentVersionKey":  "child_vesrion_1"},
                    in: {
                        child_id:'$$c._id',
                        start_date : '$$c.startDate',
                        current_version_Key : '$$currentVersionKey',
                        active_child_name : '$$c.currentVersionKey.childName'
                    }
                }
              },
            },
          },
        },
       },
     {
        $project: {
          child: 0,
        },
      },
    ])
```

In the response (finalList) i need active child name. I am taking a variable "currentVersionKey" and assigning value as "child_vesrion_1" and using that variable to find the value in "chilednodes". I am not able to get active childname.

*NOTE : For testing i have hardcoded "currentVersionKey". But it will be populated dynamically*

Here is my expected result;

```
{
    "_id" : "5e6c70e8996ddf1c28e14504",
    "startDate" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
    "active_id" : "child_vesrion_1",
    "child_id" : "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf30",
    "finalList" : [
        {
            "child_id" : "5e5e2cd4e972a95b6c32b5bf30",
            "start_date" : "2020-02-25T14:01:58.697Z",
            "current_version_Key" : "child_vesrion_1",
            "active_child_name" : "xyz"
        }
    ]
}
```

But i am not getting "active_child_name" : "xyz" in the response. Any helps on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$lookup pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#lookup-join-pipeline),

```
 db.parent.aggregate([
    { $match: { "_id": "5e6c70e8996ddf1c28e14504" } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "childnodes",
            let: { "child_id": "$child_id", "activeid": "$active_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { "$expr": { $eq: ["$_id", "$$child_id"] } } },
                {
                    $project: {
                        "child_id": "$_id",
                        "start_date": "$startDate",
                        "current_version_Key": "$active",
                        "active_child_name": {
                            "$reduce": {
                                "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
                                "initialValue": "",
                                "in": {
                                    "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$$this.k", "$$activeid"] },
                                        "$$this.v.childName",
                                        "$$value"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "finalList",
        },
    }
])
```